# How to recreate this raised letter effect in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-effects

[image]

Wasn't sure how to describe it but I'm referring to how it looks as if the illustration is plastered over "2020"

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

The 2020 is an effected image layer on the base image. It uses blending modes to make an illusion of 3D shading, but the perspective distortion is missing, so the image is still flat.
We can create the effect in Photoshop with layer styles and blending mode Hard Light:

[image]

The background image cannot have large white areas because they would make highlights invisible. Thus the screenshot is a little darkened.

Note, how the upper edge of O seems to distort text "letter effect in Photoshop" Bare shading affects so strongly that the eye sees the missing distortion.

The white gloss is actually above text ZOB. It's a white drop shadow.

Without any effects the image has 50% grey text as a separate layer:

[image]

Layer blending mode Hard light fades the grey text body, but the drop shadow is white, so it stays.

[image]

Bevel&Emboss is the rest of the shading. It creates strong highlights which are only a little lighter than 50% grey and deep shadows which are only a little darker than 50% grey. Thus the result is a mild shading with blending mode Hard Light. As well one could have full white and black, but with reduced opacity.

[image]

It's well possible that by using a more complex Bevel&Emboss light profile curve one could get a satisfying result with one effect. If one wants the mid highlight, it could be Inner Glow. Gradient map gives still more possibilities. for controlled richness. Here's a test without drop shadow. Also some random pushes are made with the liquify tool to distort the background:

[image]

Proper perspective distortion with the liquify tool seems to be very difficult. I skip further tests. A semiautomatic, but still only fake tool for perspective distortion is the displacement map. Perfect result needs a 3D model.